# Box-api file upload timeout

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, box-api

I have been fighting with this upload problem for a couple of days and searched the forum for a good answer but have not seen it yet. I am using asp.net and I am currently receiving a timeout when I try to post a file to upload. I have taken the MultipartWebRequest class from the V1 C# Api and changed it(i believe to be correctly but it may be my problem) to work with my program.

```
public sealed class MultipartWebRequest
{
    public string AcceptCharset { get; set; }
    public string AcceptEncoding { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public string Boundary { get; set; }
    public string ApiKey { get; private set; }
    public string Token { get; private set; }

    public MultipartWebRequest(string apiKey, string token, string submitUrl,string acceptCharset = "ISO-8859-1", string acceptEncoding = "gzip,deflate" )
    {
        Boundary = "----------------" + DateTime.Now.Ticks;
        ApiKey = apiKey;
        Token = token;
        Url = submitUrl;
        AcceptCharset = acceptCharset;
        AcceptEncoding = acceptEncoding;
    }

    public string SubmitFiles(
                    //string[] filePaths,
                    UploadableFile[] files,
                    bool isShared,
                    string message,
                    string[] emailsToNotify,
                    string folderId)
    {
        byte[] buffer;

        using (MemoryStream resultStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            if (files != null)
            {
                buffer = AssembleFilesBlock(files, folderId);
                resultStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(message))
            {
                buffer = AssembleMessageBlock(message);
                resultStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            }

            //buffer = AssembleSharedBlock(isShared);
            //resultStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

            if (emailsToNotify != null)
            {
                buffer = AssembleEmailsBlock(emailsToNotify);
                resultStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            }

            buffer = GetFormattedBoundary(true);
            resultStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

            resultStream.Flush();
            buffer = resultStream.ToArray();
        }

        HttpWebRequest myRequest = CreateRequest(buffer.Length);

        using (Stream stream = myRequest.GetRequestStream())
        {
            stream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            stream.Close();
        }

        string response;

        using (HttpWebResponse myHttpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myRequest.GetResponse())
        using (Stream responseStream = myHttpWebResponse.GetResponseStream())
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
            response = reader.ReadToEnd();
            responseStream.Close();
        }
        myHttpWebResponse.Close();
        return response;
    }

    private byte[] GetFormattedBoundary(bool isEndBoundary)
    {
        string template = isEndBoundary ? "--{0}--{1}" : "--{0}{1}";
        return Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(string.Format(template, Boundary, Environment.NewLine));
    }

    private byte[] AssembleEmailsBlock(string[] emailsToNotify)
    {
        return new byte[1];
    }

    private byte[] AssembleSharedBlock(bool isShared)
    {
        byte[] boundaryContent = GetFormattedBoundary(false);
        return new byte[1];
    }

    private byte[] AssembleMessageBlock(string message)
    {
        return new byte[1];
    }

    private byte[] AssembleFilesBlock(UploadableFile[] files, string folderId)
    {
        byte[] buffer = null;

        using (MemoryStream resultStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < files.Length ; i++)
            {
                buffer = GetFormattedBoundary(false);
                resultStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

                buffer = AssembleFile(files[i]);
                resultStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            }

            buffer = GetFormattedBoundary(false);
            resultStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

            buffer = AssembleStringValue("folder_id", folderId);
            resultStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

            resultStream.Flush();
            buffer = resultStream.ToArray();
        }
        return buffer;
    }

    private byte[] AssembleStringValue(string paramName, string paramValue)
    {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

        result.AppendFormat("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"{0}\"{1}", paramName, Environment.NewLine);
        result.AppendLine();
        result.AppendLine(paramValue);

        return Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(result.ToString());
    }

    private byte[] AssembleFile(UploadableFile file)
    {
        byte[] buffer;
        using (MemoryStream resultStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(string.Format("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"{0}\"; filename=\"{1}\"{2}", Guid.NewGuid(), file.FileName, Environment.NewLine));

            resultStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

            buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Content-Type: application/octet-stream" + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine);
            resultStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

            buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(file.FileContents);
            //buffer = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);

            resultStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

            buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Environment.NewLine);
            resultStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

            resultStream.Flush();
            buffer = resultStream.ToArray();
        }
        return buffer;
    }

    private HttpWebRequest CreateRequest(long contentLength)
    {
        HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(Url);
        webRequest.Method = "POST";
        //webRequest.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = true;
        webRequest.ContentType = string.Concat("multipart/form-data;boundary=", Boundary);
        webRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", "BoxAuth api_key=" + ApiKey + "&auth_token=" + Token);
        webRequest.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", AcceptEncoding);
        webRequest.Headers.Add("Accept-Charset", AcceptCharset);
        webRequest.ContentLength = contentLength;
        webRequest.ServicePoint.ConnectionLeaseTimeout = 0;

        return webRequest;
    }
}
```

Here is my default asp.net page... This is mainly just a testing page. And I can to GET requests and login and get the token and folders and everything else.

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public const string APIKEY = "{APIKEY}";
    public const string AUTH_STRING = "https://www.box.com/api/1.0/auth/";
    public const string GET_TOKEN_STRING = "https://www.box.com/api/1.0/rest?action=get_auth_token&api_key={0}&ticket={1}";
    public const string BASE_URL = "https://api.box.com/2.0/";

    public string ticket = "";
    public string token = "";
    public string login = "";

    public BoxUser boxUser;

    HttpContext http;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        http = HttpContext.Current;
        ticket = http.Request["ticket"];
        token = http.Request["auth_token"];
        login = http.Request["login"];
    }

    protected void btnBoxLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string bURL = "https://www.box.com/api/1.0/rest?action=get_ticket&api_key=" + APIKEY;
        HttpWebRequest wGetUrl = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(bURL);
        wGetUrl.ServicePoint.ConnectionLeaseTimeout = 0;

        WebResponse response = wGetUrl.GetResponse();
        Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();

        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);

        if (reader != null)
        {
            string xmlString = "";
            string tmpString = reader.ReadLine();
            while (tmpString != null)
            {
                xmlString += tmpString;
                tmpString = reader.ReadLine();
            }

            //txtResponse.Text = xmlString;
            GetResponseTicket(xmlString);
        }

        if(ticket != "")
            txtResponse.Text = "\nThe Ticket returned is: " + ticket;
        response.Close();
        stream.Close();
        Response.Redirect(AUTH_STRING + ticket, false);
    }

    protected void btnGetAuthToken_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string bURL = "https://www.box.com/api/1.0/rest?action=get_auth_token&api_key="+APIKEY+"&ticket=" + ticket;
        HttpWebRequest wGetUrl = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(bURL);
        wGetUrl.ServicePoint.ConnectionLeaseTimeout = 0;

        WebResponse response = wGetUrl.GetResponse();

        Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();

        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
        if (reader != null)
        {
            string xmlString = "";
            string tmpString = reader.ReadLine();
            while (tmpString != null)
            {
                xmlString += tmpString;
                tmpString = reader.ReadLine();
            }

            //txtResponse.Text = xmlString;
            GetResponseUser(xmlString);
        }
        //txtResponse.Text += token + "\n";
        //txtResponse.Text += login;
        response.Close();
        reader.Close();
        stream.Close();
    }

    protected void btnGetUserFolderInfo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string usersUrl = "folders/0/items";
        string url = BASE_URL + usersUrl;
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "BoxAuth api_key=" + APIKEY + "&auth_token=" + token);
        request.ServicePoint.ConnectionLeaseTimeout = 0;

        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();

        Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);

        JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        object o = js.DeserializeObject(reader.ReadLine());

        if (reader != null)
        {
            string txt = reader.ReadLine();
            txtResponse.Text += "\n" + txt;
            while (!reader.EndOfStream)
            {
                txt = reader.ReadToEnd();
                txtResponse.Text += "\n" + txt;
            }
        }
        stream.Close();
        response.Close();
        reader.Close();
    }

    private void GetResponseTicket(string xmlString)
    {
        using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xmlString)))
        {
            reader.ReadToFollowing("status");
            string status = reader.ReadElementContentAsString();

            if (status != null && status == "get_ticket_ok")
            {
                ticket = reader.ReadElementContentAsString();
                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(ticket))
                    throw new Exception("Ticket was empty");
            }
            else
                throw new Exception("For some reason Status was null or not right");
        }
    }

    private void GetResponseUser(string xmlString)
    {
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.LoadXml(xmlString);
        XmlNode root = doc.DocumentElement;
        XmlNode user = root.LastChild;
        //XmlNamespaceManager xmlns = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);

        //XmlNode node = root.SelectSingleNode(login).InnerText

        string login = user.SelectSingleNode("login").InnerText;
        string email = user.SelectSingleNode("email").InnerText;
        string access_id = user.SelectSingleNode("access_id").InnerText;
        string user_id = user.SelectSingleNode("user_id").InnerText;
        long space_amount = long.Parse(user.SelectSingleNode("space_amount").InnerText);
        long space_used = long.Parse(user.SelectSingleNode("space_used").InnerText);
        long max_upload_size = long.Parse(user.SelectSingleNode("max_upload_size").InnerText);

        boxUser = new BoxUser(login, email, access_id, user_id, space_amount, space_used, max_upload_size);
    }

    protected void CreateNewFolder_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string url = BASE_URL + "folders/389813359";

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "BoxAuth api_key=" + APIKEY + "&auth_token=" + token);
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ServicePoint.ConnectionLeaseTimeout = 0;

        ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
        string postData = "{\"name\":\"" + txtNewFolderName.Text+"\"}";
        byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(postData);

        using (Stream datastream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            datastream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            datastream.Close();
        }

        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
        Console.WriteLine(((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);

        Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();

        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
        string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
        lblResult.Text = responseFromServer;
        reader.Close();
        stream.Close();
        response.Close();
    }

    protected void UploadNewFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //string url = BASE_URL + "files/data";
        string url = "https://upload.box.com/api/2.0/" + "files/data";
        //string url = "https://upload.box.com/api/1.0/upload" + token + "/0";
        /*string boundary = "----------------------" + DateTime.Now.Ticks;
        var newLine = Environment.NewLine;
        string propFormat = "--" + boundary + newLine + "Content-Disposition: form-data; {0}={1}" + newLine;

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "BoxAuth api_key=" + APIKEY + "&auth_token=" + token);
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Post;
        request.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary;

        string fileName = fileUpload.FileName;
        byte[] file = fileUpload.FileBytes;

        using (Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
            string tmp = String.Format(propFormat, fileName, file);

            writer.Write(tmp);
            tmp = String.Format(propFormat, "folder_id", "389813359");
            writer.Write(tmp);
            writer.Write("--" + boundary + "--");
            writer.Flush();
        }

        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
        using (Stream resStream = response.GetResponseStream())
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(resStream);
            lblResult.Text = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }*/

        Stream stream = fileUpload.PostedFile.InputStream;
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
        string text = reader.ReadToEnd();

        UploadableFile file = new UploadableFile(fileUpload.FileName, text, ".txt");

        UploadableFile[] files = new UploadableFile[1];
        files[0] = new UploadableFile(fileUpload.FileName, text, ".txt"); ;
        MultipartWebRequest myRequest = new MultipartWebRequest(APIKEY,token,url);
        string response = myRequest.SubmitFiles(files, false, null, new string[] { }, "0");
        txtResponse.Text = response;
    }
}
```

As you can see I have tried all of the different upload urls that I have found around the site. And with all the different ones, not sure exactly which one to use, but [doc](https://upload.box.com/api/2.0/) appears to be the latest "most" correct one? Any help with this would be greatly appreciated as I am fairly new (but understand) to post requests in C#, but VERY new (never done one) to multipart forms in C# (or really anywhere).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current recommended URL for the API (including file uploads) appears to now be https://api.box.com/2.0.  Have you tried using that base URL?

Comment: Thank you, Yes I failed to retry this one while fighting with it. It works now, and thankfully I got my webrequest stuff right the first time!